# What controls the MAXIMUM allowed frequency of the sound in electronics? The circuit or the speaker component?

Tags: audio, sound, ultrasound

I noticed that on some of my devices, I cannot go further than 22.0 kHz, 32.0 kHz, 44.1 kHz, 48.0 kHz and such but what actually causes these limits?

Comment: Those aren't the maximum audio frequency; they are the sample rate. What caused the 44.1kHz limit was the need to adapt and re-use video recording technology in a pioneering 1970s digital audio system (3 samples per active line)

Comment: Have a look at the Nyquist sampling theorem.

Comment: What does 48.0 kHz sound like?

Answer (score 2):

Those are available sampling rates, not maximum frequencies of the audio signal. Sampling rates imply a maximum audio signal frequency of less than half of the sampling rate – but that's just an upper limit. You, as a human, can't hear beyond 20 kHz, usually (lab-condition experiments suggest you might hear loud tones above that, but that's irrelevant to normal volume audio reproduction).

The maximum reproducible audio frequency might *also* be limited by analog things (your speakers not going higher than say 20 kHz), and by the filtering of the digital-to-analog conversion stage, and the filtering inherent to your amplifier.

> what actually causes these limits?

Depends. The fact that these devices have a discrete set of available sampling rates is a matter of convention: What would it help you if one of your devices supported say 50 kHz, but none of the others? Seems like a nice, round number, but doesn't help you.

That's why 44.1 kHz and 48 kHz are so common: They have been used in commercially successful storage media and that "seeped" into end devices. For example, 44.1 kHz was simply the rate that the CD uses – and hence it becomes so standard (and the CD uses it because some previously existing studio technology used it). 48 kHz is a studio standard by the AES (Audio Engineer Society), and hence what a lot of studio equipment "naturally" uses.

Technically, sampling rates above 48 kHz definitely don't make sense; you can't hear things above 24 kHz, so storing or transporting them is of no benefit to a system. (Whether or not you need more than 44.1 kHz at all: I personally doubt it matters, but there's people with strong opinions and untested hearing on that...)

The reason hardware isn't built to support *arbitrary* rates is that it's actually hard to

1. Generate arbitrary oscillators of high reliability (at least historically – gotten way better the last 15 years)
2. Coordinate and convert between arbitrary sampling rates rather than between a limited set of them. You need resamplers – and a good rational resampler is typically lower-complexity than a comparable good arbitrary one.

The fact that your equipment supports *multiple* sampling rates *at all* is probably to

1. ensure compatibility and
2. out of "we have it anyway in our silicon".

Notice that these restrictions don't apply very much to software-based signal processing: Your computer doesn't care whether your signal is sampled at 48 or 96 kS/s; it's just a sequence of numbers to the computer. The latter rate only means that it has to process twice as many samples per second, and that filters of the same steepness are twice as long, typically, meaning you quadruple your CPU load. That might not be a big deal for your PC dealing with only few sample streams at once, but it becomes intense in large studio settings, telephony applications with thousands of participants or when you're trying to make a digital hearing aid work on a coin cell for more than a day.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the chips or their buses can't work at higher frequency. Those choises are just common default rates that are enough to play most commonly found audio files. Some types of files only support some of the rates so not all codecs can support all rates. Also for storing audio that is meant to be consumed by humans, you don't need to store frequencies higher than what human hearing is capable of so 48 kHz sampling rate is good enough. Compared to 44.1 kHz, 48 kHz adds nothing that humans can hear, but higher rate enables the use of less steep reconstruction filters after the DAC, so it can use less components and it is therefore cheaper.

Comment: So why do we have both 44.1kHz and 48kHz? Isn't 44.1kHz high enough? Why do say that the "chips or their buses" can't work at higher frequency when processors routinely operate at much, much higher clock frequencies?

Comment: If you buy a cheap codec, it just does not support higher rates, even if a multi-gigaherz CPU could send higher rates. We have different rates for different standards. 32 kHz for radio, 44.1 kHz for CD and 48 kHz for DAT. As DAT has slightly higher sampling rate, cheaper anti-alias filter can be used after the DAC.

Comment: "after the DAC" is entirely the wrong place for an anti-aliasing filter. A reconstruction filter, sure.

Comment: Thanks. Can't edit it though, so I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

From what I recall, Philipps Corp wanted to fit a certain long symphony onto a CD.

Constraints flows from that.

I've also read that humans can detect as small a time-shift as 10 microSeconds.

Comment: I think that was the reason the CD had, given the already-decided sampling rate, the strange 70something recording length, not the other way around.

Comment: That constraint was allegedly from Morita-san himself, president of Sony. The Philips CD could hold an hour, sampled at 14 bits, on a 4 inch (or so) disc. Sony insisted on 16 bits, and about 75 minutes, to hold Beethoven's 9th, without changing discs -- but their prototype was a 12 inch disc! They compromised by adapting Philips tech to a slightly larger (4.75 inch) disc to meet these requirements. (and 44.1 kHz came from the PAL version of Sony's PCM1600 (1610?) recorder using video cassettes (presumably Betamax). Odd fact : the US version sampled at 44.056 kHz thanks to the NTSC ...

Comment: NTSC frame rate of 59.94 Hz)

Answer (score -1):

max analog f??  *The circuit or the speaker component?*

- either one or both . In theory if can hear 18kHz for phase coherence we need at least 10x the bandwidth or 180kHz but only bats using sonar and freaking audiophiles who expect perfect sound recordings would ever demand this.

The more bits of resolution you have , the higher your sampling  rate must be.

At the lowest resolution Nyquest theory states you only need to sample  at twice the rate but that is just to detect it with 1 bit resolution. So the reality for quality and resolution is much higher than 2x.

Comment: Why do you say that the sampling rate must increase if the ADC resolution increases? The required sampling rate depends on the frequency characteristics of the input signal such as to avoid aliasing. The resolution of the ADC increases the dynamic range of the system but does not affect its frequency response.

Comment: Barry I said Sampling rate must increase not the frequency response , part 1 analog limit... part 2 digital limits

Comment: Barry you do understand that Nyquist sampling rate ratio to BW is binary ie resolution of 1 bit. so increasing number of bits increases that ratio.  right?  Who is -1?